# Docker image: virtual size vs real size

Tags: docker

This is the output of my docker images command:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY      TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
redis           3.0.0          6b81c9436dd1   17 months ago   111.1 MB
nginx           1.7            d5acedd7e96a   17 months ago   93.45 MB
```

Those images share a common layer (`debian:jessie`, size 85MB), as you can see [here](http://imagelayers.iron.io/?images=redis:3.0.0,nginx:1.7). Standing at this output the two images should takes 204.5MB of my disk space, but as fa as I know (due to the shared layer) these images should use only 119.55MB of my disk space (i.e. 204.5MB - 85MB).

Is this assumption right? 
Why the header "VIRTUAL SIZE" in `docker image` output has been removed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those images do share a common base layer. You can check with `docker inspect`, which for the latest versions shows they have the same base layer:

```
> docker inspect -f ' {{ .RootFS }}' redis
{layers [sha256:142a601d97936307e75220c35dde0348971a9584c21e7cb42e1f7004005432ab ...

> docker inspect -f ' {{ .RootFS }}' nginx
{layers [sha256:142a601d97936307e75220c35dde0348971a9584c21e7cb42e1f7004005432ab ...
```

As to why the label changed - the [source code](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/cli/command/image) could tell you, but I'd say "virtual image" is not an accurate description. The image size **is** the image size - it's the space you need if you were to pull the image onto a clean box.